# Using Python Mechanize like "Tamper Data"

Tags: python, forms, mechanize, tampering

I'm writing a web testing script with python (2.6) and mechanize (0.1.11).  The page I'm working with has an html form with a select field like this:

```
<select name="field1" size="1">
    <option value="A" selected>A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```

In mechanize, if I try something like this:

```
browser.form['field1'] = ['E']
```

Then I get an error: `ClientForm.ItemNotFoundError: insufficient items with name 'E'`

I can do this manually with the "Tamper Data" firefox extension.  Is there a way to do this with python and mechanize?  Can I somehow convince mechanize that the form actually has the value I want to submit?

Comment: In the example you gave, it *doesn't* have the value 'E'.

Comment: That's the point, I want to trick it into submitting 'E', even though that's not one of the listed options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After poking around with the guts of ClientForm, it looks like you can trick it into adding another item.

For a select field, something like this seems to work:

```
xitem = ClientForm.Item(browser.form.find_control(name="field1"), 
        {'contents':'E', 'value':'E', 'label':'E'})
```

Similarly, for a radio button control

```
xitem = ClientForm.Item(browser.form.find_control(name="field2"),
        {'type':'radio', 'name':'field2', 'value':'X'})
```

Note that the Item initializer will automatically update the list of items for the specified control, so you only need to create the item properly for it to appear.